# Value is never set on Object C#

Tags: c#, list, object

```
public static List < Item > itemList = new List < Item > ();
public class Item {
  public int id;
  public int price, stock;
  public Item(int id, int price, int stock) {
    id = this.id;
    price = this.price;
    stock = this.stock;
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
  Item first = new Item(1, 23, 2);
  Item second = new Item(2, 345, 5);
  itemList.Add(first);
  itemList.Add(second);

  foreach(var item in itemList) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.price);
  }
}
```

When I loop through the list it always prints out 0 and not the actual price set on my first and second items. How can set the values correctly?

Comment: You should move this to the left, like this.id = id, and alle others

Comment: `price = this.price;` Before this line, check the value of the `price` parameter. After this line, check the value of the `price` parameter. What do you notice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement to member variable assignment in the constructor should be

```
this.id = id
```

where `this` is used to qualify the class member field/property.

You can read about `this` usage at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this)

```
public Item(int id, int price, int stock) 
{
    this.id = id;
    this.price = price;
    this.stock = stock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your `Item class` and in constructor You wrote the opposite
you must write this constructor:

```
 public Item(int id, int price, int stock)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.price = price;
    this.stock = stock;
  }
```